# Can I get route parameter through controller constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new with ASP.NET and cannot find a elegant solution to remove redundant code.
I have multiple controller accessing objects from a larger List<>, like users, matches etc...

How do I do that right?

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/{user_id}")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class UserController
{
    private Event _event = EventContainer.Instance.Event;


    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<User> GetJoinedUserById(int user_id)
    {
        var res = _event.JoinedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == user_id);
        if (res == null)
            return null;

        return res;
    }

    [HttpGet("secret")]
    public ActionResult<string> GetWebHookSecret(int user_id)
    {
        var res = _event.JoinedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == user_id);
        if (res == null)
            return "";

        return res.WebHookSecret;
    }

    [HttpGet("builds")]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Build>> GetJoinedUsers(int user_id)
    {
        var res = _event.JoinedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == user_id);
        if (res == null)
            return null;

        return res.Builds;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to move the `FirstOrDefault` line to a constructor of sort?

```cs
public UserController(int user_id)
{
    var res = _event.JoinedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == user_id);
    if (res == null)
        return BadRequest();
        
    _user = res;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to abstract the `User` retrieval is by providing a [custom model binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-model-binder-sample) for the type. First, create a class implementing `IModelBinder`:

```
public class UserBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private Event _event = EventContainer.Instance.Event;

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // This is very minimal, you'll likely want to do more validation, etc.
        var user_id = int.Parse(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("user_id").FirstValue);
        var res = _event.JoinedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == user_id);
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(res);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Next, add the `ModelBinder` attribute to the `User` class:

```
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(UserBinder))]
public class User { ... }
```

And then in the controller you can simply pass the `User` type as the endpoint parameter:

```
public class UserController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<User> GetJoinedUserById(User user) => user;

    [HttpGet("secret")]
    public ActionResult<string> GetWebHookSecret(User user) => user?.WebHookSecret ?? "";

    [HttpGet("builds")]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Build>> GetJoinedUsers(User user) => user?.Builds;
}
```

Comment: That really is an elegant solution. +1

Comment: nice solution. now i just need to figure out how to hide the "User user" from Swagger, it now adds a non-required parameter for it

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access `user_id` in the constructor. Because the value of any route parameter will not be available until the call reaches an action method.

If your requirement is only to reduce code redundancy, then you can create a private method -

```cs
private User GetUser(int id)
{
    return _event.JoinedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

and call it from all your action methods, like -

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<User> GetJoinedUserById(int user_id)
{
    var res = this.GetUser(user_id);
    if (res == null)
        return null;

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would handle it:

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/{user_id}")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class UserController : ManagedController
{
   private readonly int userId;

   public UserController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
   {
       this.userId = GetRouteId("user_id", httpContextAccessor);
   }
}
```

the ManagedController would look like this:

```
public abstract class ManagedController : Controller
{
 protected int GetRouteId(string parameterName, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
 {
     if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext != null && httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues.ContainsKey(parameterName))
     {
         var routeValue = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues[parameterName];
         if (routeValue != null)
         {
             int id;
             if (int.TryParse(routeValue.ToString(), out id))
             {
                 return id;
             }
             else
             {
                 throw new Exception($"{parameterName} is not an integer");
             }
         }
         else
         {
             throw new Exception($"{parameterName} is null");
         }
     }
     else
     {
         throw new Exception($"{parameterName} not found in route");
     }
 }
 }
```

And in your Startup.cs (or where you configure your services), you would have to add:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```